# Associate int array with string array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a function that gives me an output of an int array which always has a length of 5, where the values are either 1 or 0. Here are a few examples of possible outputs:

```
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0] or [0, 0, 1, 0, 1] or [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Using this as an input, I need to create a function in Java that will associate this int array with an array of strings, where a 1 indicates that the string will be in the array and a 0 indicates that it won't be in the array. For instance:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1] => ["Tweet", "Email", "Text", "Phone Call", "Voicemail"]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1] => ["", "Email", "Text", "",  "Voicemail"]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] => ["", "", "", "", ""]
```

All I can think of is doing something like this:

```
public String[] myFunc(int[] arr) {

  String[] output = [5];

  for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    switch (i) {
      case 0:
        if (arr[i] == 1)
          output[i] = "Tweet";
        else
          output[i] = "";
        break;

      case 1:
        if (arr[i] == 1)
          output[i] = "Email";
        else
          output[i] = "";
        break;

      case 2:
        if (arr[i] == 1)
          output[i] = "Text";
        else
          output[i] = "";
        break;

      case 3:
        if (arr[i] == 1)
          output[i] = "Phone Call";
        else
          output[i] = "";
        break;

      case 4:
        if (arr[i] == 1)
          output[i] = "Voicemail";
        else
          output[i] = "";
        break;
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

This is a pretty ugly solution, and I'm sure it can be done better by implementing some kind of object to map the values but I am not too familiar with Java and would appreciate any help!

Comment: `IntStream.range(0, ints.length).map(i -> ints[i] == 0 ? "" : strings[i]).toArray(String[]::new)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    boolean[] booleanArray = new boolean[] { true, false, true, false, true };
    String[] stringArray = new String[] { "Tweet", "Email", "Text", "Phone Call", "Voicemail" };
    String[] stringResult = new String[5];
    for (int i=0;i<booleanArray.length;i++) {
        if (booleanArray[i]) {
            stringResult[i] = stringArray[i];
        } else {
            stringResult[i] = "";
        }
    }
```